# Does AWS CloudFormation have an equivalent Terraform destroy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Having deployed an application using Amazons AWS SAM framework (CloudFormation under the hood) I would now like to destroy all the resources it has created.

This is easy enough to do had I been using Terraform with the Terraform destroy command.  Is there an equivalent command using AWS SAM or even CloudFormation?

Thanks in adv.
Michael McD.

Comment: AFAIK, all `Cloudformation` CLI or SDK APIs work for SAM since SAM (as you said) is `Cloudformation` under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the cloudformation stack (and therefore all resources contained within it) either through the cli (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/delete-stack.html) or through the console (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-delete-stack.html).